# Optimizing Firebase requests

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Google Map Api to get locations. It returns a list of locations.  I want to check to see if any of those locations are already in my database. If so will get some information for that location if not, I will add it as a new location in my firebase database. What I am currently doing is that I would read my entire database as an array and then start going through that array and comparing the items in the arrays.

That is is really expensive and slows down my app. Any suggestions on how I can better it. I attached my code. Thanks

```
            .then(response => {
                // result [] is the list of locations that I get from the google map APi call.
                // response [] is the list of my entire data from my database.
                const objects = Object.keys(response)
                if (response === null){
                    console.log("error")
                }else{

                    for (const key in result){
                        const current = new Location(result[key].id, result[key].name, result[key].geometry.location.lat, result[key].geometry.location.lng, '', '')
                        for(const curr in response){
                            if (result[key].id === response[curr].id){
                                current.reportStatus = response[curr].reportStatus
                                current.reportTime = response[curr].reportTime
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        search.push(current)
                        const index = objects.indexOf(result[key].id)
                        if (index ===-1){
                            const url = "url"
                            putInDatabase(url,result[key].id, result[key].name, result[key].geometry.location.lat, result[key].geometry.location.lng, '', '')
                        }

                    }
                    setData(search)
                    
                }

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
```

Comment: May be you could do something like pagination (this is like divide data) for that. It's useful when you need to load  many info.

For example: Fetch the first 10 items. If you need to get the next "page", you should fetch the next 10 so now you have 20 items and still working fast.

You need to find a good approach in UI to show the info that you need

Here is some extra info to give you an idea of how this works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination

Comment: Thank you @FrankVanPuffelen. I tried a different approach. Instead of reading the entire data, I would just loop through the result that I got from the GoogleMap Api and make the request for each item separately. That made the runtime linear run time instead of a polynomial runtime.